# Execute external command and read stderr/stdout from Jython 2.1

Tags: java, file-io, jython, stderr

I'm executing an external command from Jython 2.1 by calling `os.system()`. This works, but I can't get to any error messages the external program is writing.

Jython 2.1 is too old to use `subprocess` and `os.popen` does not seem to exist in Jython 2.1.

How can I capture stderr and stdout of my external program inside my Jython script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never coded in Jython but as far as I know you can use any java class from Jython code. I am sorry if my suggestion is stupid but why not to call java's ProcessBuilder from your Jython script? ProcessBuilder has this functionality.

Comment: Thanks. My Java knowledge is very limited and hopelessly out of date. I just did not know how to do this effectively in Java. I'll try it out.